# jQuery - Stop listening for scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am using this code to perform tasks when the user scrolls:

```
function myFunction(){
var position = $(window).scrollTop();

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(scroll > position) {
         // scrolling downwards
         hypeDocument.showSceneNamed('Section 2', hypeDocument.kSceneTransitionCrossfade, 1.1);
    }
    position = scroll;
});

return false;
}
```

But I would like to prevent down scrolling on one page. Is there anyway I can do this whilst allowing the scroll on the other pages? I tried using `$(window).off("scroll");` but that blocks scrolling in both directions.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154967/jquery-detect-scrolldown

Comment: How do you define page?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817158/how-do-i-prevent-scroll-down-in-javascript

Comment: @AmirGeri I am using an HTML5 animation software which uses 'scenes' see the special syntax `hypeDocument.showSceneNamed` etc. basically i want to run a script on the load of a scene to prevent detection of downward scroll.

Comment: @metamorph_online I've just had a look there but that seems to be for when the down arrow is pressed. Not just in general.

Comment: @m90 That basically does what I already have, it prints when they scroll down and when they scroll up. I need to prevent the down scroll

Comment: Can you provide an example in JSFiddle or something?

Answer (score 0):

This will completely disable scrolling:

```
$('html, body').css({
    'overflow': 'hidden',
    'height': '100%'
});
```

To restore:

```
$('html, body').css({
    'overflow': 'auto',
    'height': 'auto'
});
```

Comment: as I understood the top scroll is used by user to trigger some actions... so this is not the right solution.

Comment: I need to block downward only.

Answer (score 0):

If you only wish to prevent scrolling in the vertical direction (up and down), you can set the scroll in that direction to hidden:

`overflow-y: hidden`

You could trigger that effect with jQuery using:

`$('body').css('overflow-y','hidden');`

Comment: I only want to prevent scrolling down. I want to allow scrolling up.